# How do I run Kotlin code using OkHttp from the command line?

Tags: kotlin, okhttp

I tried running Kotlin code on macOS 13 from the command line, first I installed it with

```bash
brew install kotlin
```

then I made a directory and downloaded the latest versions of some jar files that seemed relevant:

```bash
mkdir -p /tmp/kotlin 
cd /tmp/kotlin 
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/4.11.0/okhttp-4.11.0.jar > okhttp-4.11.0.jar 
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/squareup/okio/okio/3.3.0/okio-3.3.0.jar > okio-3.3.0.jar 
curl https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.8.21/kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar > kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar
```

(ChatGPT told me to install kotlin-stdlib too, I'm not sure that makes sense...)

then I created a sample file called OkHttpExample.kt with these contents:

```kotlin
import java.io.IOException;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request

fun main() {
    val client = OkHttpClient()

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url("https://example.com")
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
        if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

        println(response.body!!.string())
    }
}
```

and tried to compile and run it

```bash
kotlinc -classpath okhttp-4.11.0.jar:kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar:okio-3.3.0.jar OkHttpExample.kt -include-runtime -d OkHttpExample.jar
java -classpath okhttp-4.11.0.jar:kotlin-stdlib-1.8.21.jar:okio-3.3.0.jar:OkHttpExample.jar OkHttpExampleKt
```

but the `java` command fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Buffer
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion.create(ResponseBody.kt:248)
    at okhttp3.ResponseBody$Companion.create$default(ResponseBody.kt:247)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.<clinit>(Util.kt:65)
    at okhttp3.OkHttpClient.<clinit>(OkHttpClient.kt:1073)
    at OkHttpExampleKt.main(OkHttpExample.kt:6)
    at OkHttpExampleKt.main(OkHttpExample.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: okio.Buffer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Well from looking at the error it keeps pointing to "main" and no "java.lang.class" is not found.  Don't you need that class to run that portion of the core code?

Comment: Also just curious as to why your doing it this way. I use MacBook Pro, and I just downloaded the installer from the Android Website. Are you trying to run kotlin outside of Android Studio or trying to use Android Studio?

Comment: @CampNerd I'm working on [a transpiler](https://curlconverter.com/kotlin/) written in javascript that transpiles code into Kotlin (and 15 other languages) and I want to test that the code it transpiles to performs the same operation as the original code, which I've been doing for all other languages by running that code [through the shell](https://github.com/curlconverter/curlconverter/blob/59b5c974b05ca335c7aefc63ede0b81cf11bfcd1/tools/compare-requests.ts#L67)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fixing your specific problem

`NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Buffer` means that some code tries to use the `okio.Buffer` class but the class is not in any jar that you put on the classpath.

This may happen because you just manually cherry-picked some jars to download, and you missed transitive dependencies. For instance, it's likely you're missing the `okio-jvm` dependency, which is a dependency of `okio` itself.

One solution is to find all transitive dependencies yourself (for instance by looking at `.pom` files in Maven Central) and download more and more jars by hand, but it's not very practical.

#### Recommended approaches

Instead, I highly suggest 2 options here:

1. create a "standard" Kotlin project and use a build tool like Gradle to manage dependencies and compilation. It requires a bit of setup, but it will be more familiar to most people, and you may easily find examples online.
2. if you're just playing around, you can try to use **Kotlin Scripting** with the `.main.kts` script definition, which may simplify your workflow here, but note that it's experimental and not very well known.

I'll elaborate on option 2 here because it's harder to find information about it.

To use the main-kts definition, make sure your file ends with `.main.kts`. Then put your code directly at the top level without wrapping it in a `main()` function.

Instead of manually downloading jars, add dependencies to it using `@file:DependsOn` at the top of the file, with the maven coordinates of the dependencies (you don't need to put transitive dependencies, just the ones you want to use directly):

`script.main.kts` (the extension matters!)

```kotlin
@file:DependsOn("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.11.0")

import java.io.IOException
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.Request

val client = OkHttpClient()
val request = Request.Builder().url("https://example.com").build()
client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
    if (!response.isSuccessful) throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")

    println(response.body!!.string())
}
```

Then you can compile and run it in one simple command:

```
kotlin script.main.kts
```

Here is a more "official" example about `main.kts` usage:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-script-examples/blob/master/jvm/main-kts/MainKts.md